# Cordova CLI build Android for Specific Version?

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am using cordova and Ionic to create apps. I want to build for Android 6.0(API 23).

I have added the platform as `cordova platform add android`. This adds the Android API 25 by default.

In my project, in the **config.xml** file I have the following

`<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="23"/>`

How do can I have the latest cordova-android and build for older android APIs/

Answer (score 1):

You can run the following command:

```
$ cordova platform add android@x.x.x
```

With x.x.x is the version of Android you want to use. Be careful though, **Cordova** version must be compatible with the Android version. Here is a table explaining that.

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/

Here is also a table detailing Android build numbers:
https://source.android.com/setup/build-numbers

Comment: Let's say I want to use Android 7 (API 25) The table says cordova-android for Android 7 is 6.X.X. That means from 6.0.0 to 6.9.9 or more.Which exactly should I use for API 25.

Comment: You could use the 6.5 version you could even use the 7.1.0 version. Npm install cordova@7.1.0 -g

Comment: No i am not asking about which version of cordova should I install. I am asking which version of android should I add. As the table says 6.x.x. Which version exatly will match to API25

Comment: Apparently you don't understand what API25 means. Api 25 = Android 7.1= Android Nougat .Here's a table detailing Android build numbers https://source.android.com/setup/build-numbers

Comment: I know that. What I want know is what version of "Android-Cordova" maps to Android API version. For example, I want to build for API 25 i.e, Android 7. Then what should I add as a platform in cordova `cordova platform add android@?.?.?`

Comment: cordova platform add android@7.1

Comment: getting the following `npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for cordova-android@7.1`

Comment: Got It working by adding `cordova platform add android@6.2.3` which builds for API 25 (Android 7). I got the `6.2.3` by trial and error but wanted to know is there a table that has that.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it right, you have to use the `<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="23"/>`, that will make your app to work in API 23 and newer.

The API 25 you talk about is the target SDK used to build the app, that means it's built natively for Android 7.1, so it will work without problems in Android 7.1 and older. On Android 8 it will work in compatibility mode.

If you install a Cordova version that targets the API 23, it will work in compatibility mode in Android 7 and newer. It's always recommended to target the latest SDK (27 at the moment).